# Conditional parameter in composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a composable with defult parameter -> height = 300. Here I have condition which gives height 360 or 300 (default). Is there any way that I don't need to write the default(300) value.

I was thinking about something like ->
`MaximizedContainer(onClick = { onClick() }, if (infoOpened) {height = 360}) {}`, but this is not working.
So currently it looks like this ->
`MaximizedContainer(onClick = { onClick() }, height = if (infoOpened) 360 else 300) {}`, but I don't want to every time specify the default 300 value

````
fun MaximizedContainer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    color: Color = LightBlue,
    height: Int = 300,
    content: (@Composable () -> Unit)
) {}```
````

Comment: ```infoOpened``` is a local parameter in the parent composable of ```MaximizedContainer``` It's just a Boolean and basically if its true I would like to have higher container if not I would like to have the default hight, without having to write it manually -> 300

Answer (score 0):

Closest thing to

```
MaximizedContainer(onClick = { onClick() }, if (infoOpened) {height = 360}) {}
```

would probably be

const val defaultContainerSize = 300

```
@Composable
fun MaximizedContainer(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    color: Color = Color.Blue,
    height: () -> Int = { defaultContainerSize },
    content: (@Composable () -> Unit)
) {

    val height = height()
    content()
}
```

And you can call it like this

```
MaximizedContainer(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    height = {
        if (infoOpened) 360 else defaultContainerSize
    }
){}
```

This approach is particularly useful when you need to pass some parameters from child to parent when some internal event happens, it's even more useful when you need to pass param from child to parent and parent needs to do some calculation and return result. Also it [defers state read](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance#defer-reads) especially when you have inner Domposables and don't want ones that don't require this value to recompose.

I don't know if in your situation declaring `const val defaultContainerSize = 300` and using it as in question isn't enough?